# Занесение переменных в массив обьявленный внутри класса

Tags: php, ооп

Здравствуйте. Требуется занести данные из переменных в массив который в классе. Вот как это примерно должно выглядеть. Подскажите в чем ошибка и как правильно нужно их заносить для правильности работы кода.

```
$a = $_POST['a'];   - другие переменные получаются по аналогии

 class getMaximumFromPath {

    static $points = [
        '1' => ['3' => $a, '2' => $b, '4' => $c],
        '2' => ['5' => $d],
        '3' => ['6' => $e, '5' => $j],
        '4' => ['6' => $k],
        '5' => ['6' => $k],
    ];

    public static $startPointId = 1;
    public static $endPointId = 6;

    static function getSum($summ, $parentPointId, $pathPointId) {

        $summResult = [];

        foreach(self::$points[$parentPointId] as $key => $value) {

            if ($parentPointId == self::$startPointId) { $summ = 0; $pathPointId = self::$startPointId; }

            $summ = $summ + $value;
            $pointId = $key;
            $pathPointId = $pathPointId . "," . $pointId;

            if ($pointId != self::$endPointId) {
                $summResult = array_merge(
                    $summResult,
                    self::getSum($summ, $pointId, $pathPointId));
            } else {
                $summResult[] = [$summ, $pathPointId];
                $summ = $summ - $value;

                $pathPointId = explode(',', $pathPointId);
                unset($pathPointId[count($pathPointId) - 1]);
                $pathPointId = implode(',', $pathPointId);
            }
        }

        return $summResult;

    }
}
```